# How to find the biggest number in an array

Tags: c

I have an array with a size that I dont know(mostly a size of a 10),
that most of it has 1's and 2's, but sometimes 3's and 4's...
I cant buble sort, because the order is importhan, but other then that, I can do everything

Thanks :)

Comment: what have you tried so far? and you need to know the size of the array (even if its dynamically allocated using `malloc`).

Comment: any criteria? using loops not using loops? iteration restriction? anything? Is it a homework?

Comment: I can do loops, though I cant change the order the ints that are in the array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Iterate over the array until you hit your break condition.

While iterating (use the `for` or `while` loop), remember the highest value so far and compare against current.

Answer (score 2):

I don't have access to a compiler that supports this right now, but here's a concise example of how to do it in C++11:

```
#include <iostream>

constexpr int array[10] = { 1, 0, 2, 3, 0, 2, 7, 1, 9, 2 };

template<int maxest, int index>
struct find_biggest_r {
  enum { value = find_biggest_r<(array[index] > maxest ? array[index]:maxest),index-1>::value };
};

template<int maxest>
struct find_biggest_r<maxest,0> {
 enum { value = (array[0] > maxest ? array[0] : maxest) };
};

template<int index>
struct find_biggest {
  enum { value = find_biggest_r<array[index],index-1>::value };
};

int main()
{
    std::cout << find_biggest<9>::value;
}

//
```

Now that I'm done trolling, in C, you would do:

```
int array[4] = { 2, 1, 0, 2 };
int biggest = array[0];
for (int i = 1; i < 4; i++) { // we've already used array[0] so we start at array[1]
  if (array[i] > biggest) biggest = array[i];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I will give only the pseudocode

```
max := array[0];

for i = 1 to size
    if(array[i] > max)
     {
        max := array[i]
     }
```

Comment: This should be home work so better let him do...the OP did not post nything about what he tried so far.

Comment: @peter: Thats why I gave the pseudocode.. converting it to real `C` code has been left as an exercise to OP..I believe there is nothing wrong in giving logic even if its homework.

Comment: It isnt homework, just a small project im working on... by the way, your code did help, even if it's not in C :) I think your right, helping in logic isnt wrong, we all doesnt have an idea how to do something sometimes.. :)

Answer (score 1):

start traversing the array in a for loop.
Take a variable and by default put the first element in it and assume as the highest.
while you traverse,when ever you find an element greater than the value in the variable just replace it.
at the end of the loop the value contains the highest number.

Comment: Thanks, that's exaclly what I did :)

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:-

```
int max = array[0];    
for (int j = 1 to size)
{
    if(array[j] > max)
     {
        max = array[j];
     }
}
```